# I disagree with the approved edit made to the title of my question. Should I edit it back?

Tags: discussion, editing

My question, having been asked & answered in '15, was edited last year, but I noticed it today only & I disagree with the change.

The original question :
[Why is The Wall the only Democracy in an otherwise Westerosi Monarchy?(Minor S05E02 & Book 3 spoiler)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/86363/2)

The body of it was correctly edited for spoiler markdown & minor changes which didn't change its meaning.

I noticed today that the title was change to :
[Why is the Night's Watch the only democracy in an otherwise feudal Westeros? (Minor S05E02 & Book 3 spoilers)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86363/why-is-the-nights-watch-the-only-democracy-in-an-otherwise-feudal-westeros-mi)

**The Wall is a place & Night's Watch is an institution.** Although technically alright, monarchy, democracy et. al. are always attributed to places. For example if ISIS captures a democratic nation like USA, we will say that USA is an autocracy.

Another problem is with removing Monarchy with feudalism. **Westeros is a feudal monarchy.** It's not just a feudal state. **Power is through inheritance.** I missed adding feudal to my question. Slaver's Bay or Vaes Dothrak can be called a feudal state though but not Westeros.

So the question is, is it okay for the OP to roll back approved edits to the question if he/she disagrees with it?

Comment: Definitely. It's your question.

Comment: Except that it's not The Wall that is the democracy, it's merely the place where the institution of the Night's Watch happens to be based.

Comment: It's a bit like asking "*Why is London democratic?*" instead of asking "*Why are the Freemasons democratic?*" merely because the Freemasons are primarily based in London.

Comment: Starks controlled Winterfell, then Boltons controlled Winterfell. So will you say the Stark rule was a monarchy, the Bolton rule was a monarchy or Winterfell was a monarchy. If in the future, Dothraky capture Winterfell, would you say, Dothraky rule was autocracy or Winterfell was an autocracy. Institutions are temporary, places are permanent.

Comment: @KharoBangdo - Unless you're talking about the present,  at best you could ask "*Was **Dothraki-controlled Winterfell** an Autocracy*?". You wouldn't ask "*Why is Japan a feudal dictatorship?*", would you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ...is it okay for the OP to roll back approved edits to the question if he/she disagrees with it?

Generally, yes. The community typically defers to the wishes of the OP if the OP expresses a disagreement with the nature of an edit. There are a few exceptions in which an edit should not be rolled back even if the OP wants to do so, including but not limited to:

1. An edit which removed something offensive and/or personally identifiable information.
2. A title which needlessly reveals spoilers.
3. The OP objects to an edit which improves only the spelling, grammar, etc. (i.e. an objectively good edit).

Your disagreement with the edit does not fall under any of these exceptions and is subjective in nature so feel free to edit your post. Please be sure not to rollback objectively correct editing, such as proper capitalization.

---

You should be open to suggestions from others regarding the correct terminology, though. Personally, I find "why is the Night's Watch the only democracy" more appropriate than "why is the Wall the only democracy" as places like the Wall don't really have a form of government. I don't have enough expertise as to whether or not Westeros should be regarded as feudal or a monarchy or some more specific term, but others who are experts in the subject matter may suggest a better terminology.

Comment: I have indeed edited the question to what I feel is correct as the discussion in the comments couldn't change my mind convincingly. Thanks